# error uploading to cloud storage using a cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to upload files to google cloud storage using a cloud function which is triggered by HTTP.  However when the cloud function sends the file to be uploaded I often (although not always) get the following error

> ERROR uploading to storage: { ApiError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to bucket_name/folder/test.jpg.

I am not sure why this error occurs - and why only some of the time

Here is the code:

```
const storage      = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

function uploadToStorage(filepath, folder, filename) {
  const options = {
    destination: bucket.file(`${folder}/${filename}`),
    public: false,
    resumable: false
  };

  storage
    .bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    .upload(filepath, options)
    .then(function () {
      console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${BUCKET_NAME}`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('ERROR uploading to storage: ', err);
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How is your function triggered, is it via pubsub?

Comment: @Oliver HTTP trigger - added it to the question

Comment: Have you created a signed-URL function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error after adding a `return` statement at the end of my function that performed file deletes on storage objects. This is what I was doing:

1. Make a database call to get some data
2. Once that request comes back, delete some files out of cloud storage (GCS)

The code structurally looked like this:

```
deleteStuffOutStorage() {

    admin.firestore().doc(`My-doc-ref`).get()
        .then(snapshot => { 
            // Do the deleting here {Interacting with GCS}
            return deleteFile(snapshot.data().path); // Deletes file
        })

        .then(success => {
           // Worked
        })

        .catch(error => {
          // Error = ApiError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects...
        })

    return;   // This statement was creating the problems
}
```

When I removed the `return` statement, I no longer got the error. I thought in my case it may have something to do with **firebase-admin** object instance getting deallocated and re-allocated between asynchronous operations (**steps 1 and 2 above**), or at least its GCS auth token?

All FCF instances should have access to GCS via a service account that is auto-generated. You can confirm this in the GCP console : https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/

From the code snippet you posted I can't see anything that would cause the same issue I was getting, but maybe have a think about any time-based events that could cause this behaviour. That may explain the inconsistent behaviour you elude to.

Hope that's some sort of help.

Comment: It turns out it was caused by an asynchronous error somewhere else in the code   (I just never would have guessed it was an asynchronous error from the error message)
Thanks for your help